# Emacs flickering when using before-save-hook with gofmt

Tags: hooks, motion

I am trying to use gofmt on my go before I save it.

```
; Run gofmt before save
(setq gofmt-command "goimports")
(setq exec-path (cons "/usr/lib/go/bin" exec-path))
(add-to-list 'exec-path "/home/giodamelio/Projects/go/bin")
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save)
```

The problem is, whenever I try to move the cursor(either with C-n/C-p, or with evil), the contents of the buffer seem to flicker. It is not the entire buffer(not visual bell), and it is not the same bits of text each time.

When I comment out those four lines it goes away, so I know it has somthing to do with them, but my understanding of the `before-save-hook` is that is will only run before I save, not whenever I move the cursor"

Comment: Does the issue persist if you **only** comment the `before-save-hook`, but leave the other lines intact?

Comment: Which version of emacs? Does this happen with just these four lines in an otherwise empty emacs config?

Comment: @lunaryorn No, it is definitely the before hook,

Comment: @MrBones No, when they are by themselves(no package init or anything), the problem goes away).

Comment: That makes be think that the hook actually runs, i.e. that the buffer is frequently saved, without you typing `C-x C-s`. Do you use some auto-saving mode?

Comment: Just whatever the default is. The only thing I am doing is moving the auto save and backup dir to `~/.emacs.d/.saves`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you add both `/usr/lib/go/bin` and `/home/giodamelio/Projects/go/bin` to `exec-path`, and why do you use two different ways to add them? Are you trying to do something special here, other than prepend those entries to the list `exec-path`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load library `simple.el` (not `simple.elc`), then do `M-x debug-on-entry RET next-line RET`.

Then use `C-n` and step through the debugger using `d` (or `c` to skip through an evaluation) to see what happens (when the flickering occurs etc.).  If the flicker happens during evaluation of a function call for a function that is not defined in `simple.el`, you can load its source file too, to get better debugging about it.  And so on.

---

**Update after your comment:**

Sounds like an error is occurring during redisplay. Typically that is because of one of these:

1. An error in `post-command-hook` (or perhaps `pre-command-hook`).
2. An error in something that updates the mode line (e.g., something in `mode-line-format`).
3. An error in font-locking.

Check what you are doing in these 3 areas.  Remove stuff from `post-command-hook` to see if it stops the flickering. Likewise, if you do anything to the mode line, stop doing it to see if that stops the flickering. Similarly, turn off font-lock mode to see if that helps.

If you can stop the flickering this way then you'll know which code to investigate.  You cannot use the debugger on it (because the debugger is inhibited during redisplay). But you can add calls to `message` to print program state & other info.

Comment: I tried that, but the flicker happens whenever I do any input(`d` or `c`). It is like it is doing it on every redraw.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be git-gutter conflicting with linenum mode. I switched to [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) and it is working fine. Still not sure why it was only happening in go-mode(I tried it in other modes inside git repos), I can only guess that it was the filesize(the go file was much larger then any of the other files I tested).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that some other part of your config causes constant saves, tho I wouldn't know why nor of what.

You might like to try

```
(add-hook 'go-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save nil t)))
```

so the gofmt-before-save only happens in go-mode buffers, rather than everywhere.